# get route field parameter

Tags: php, laravel, testing

When I'm testing get route in Laravel I am getting error that token field is required.

```
$response = $this->get(route('resendsms', ['token' => $token]));
```

web route

```
Route::get('/auth/resendsms/{token}', [AuthController::class, 'resendsms'])->name('resendsms');
```

I seem not to have the right syntax

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Things I tried

```
$response = $this->get(route('resendsms', ['token' => $token]));
$response = $this->get(route('resendsms',$token));
```

Comment: does `$token` have a value? it is **NOT** `null`?

Comment: Personal answer after testing for a long time, write the full URL, do not use the name, because if the URL is `/auth/resendsms/{token}` but someone changes it by mistake o whatever to `/hello/my/name/is/{token}`, and the name of the route is still `resendsms`, you will not have the desired URL. AND, you also prevent issues like you are facing right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the example and check the parameters of the `AuthController@resendsms` method.

*This method was tested by me*

```php
Route::get('/auth/resendsms/{token}', function (string $token) {
    // ...
})->name('resendsms');
 
$url = route('resendsms', ['token' => 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9', 'photos' => 'yes']);

$response = $this->get($url);

$response->assertStatus(200);
 
// $url - /auth/resendsms/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9?photos=yes
```

Follow the example and check the parameters of the AuthController@resendsms method.

You can also use the

```
$this->call('GET', '/auth/resendsms/{token}');
```

Also be sure to clear your cache

```php
php artisan route:clear
```

I also recommend making parameters of the right type

```php
})->where(['token' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+'])->name('resendsms')
```

[Laravel Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing)

Answer (score 1):

When testing a route that requires a parameter, you should pass the parameter as part of the route URL. However, based on your code and the error you're encountering, it seems like the route definition in your web.php file is expecting the `{token}` parameter in the URL, but your test code is not providing it correctly.

Here's how you can correctly pass the token parameter when testing the route:

```php
//Assuming $token is the actual token you want to pass
$response = $this->get('/auth/resendsms/' . $token);
```

If you prefer using the route helper, you can pass the parameters as the second argument:

```
$response = $this->get(route('resendsms', ['token' => $token]));
```